# What is my interface name for MAC address?

Tags: command-line, networking, 20.04

So I’ve been trying to figure out my interface name and examples that have been shown online are related to older versions of Ubuntu such as ens and enp. An example being (enp12s0). But my interface shows something different which starts with enx and I’m running Ubuntu 20.04.

Can anyone help me decipher my interface name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have recently changed from an internal ethernet device to a USB ethernet device.

Let's start here:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

An interface name that begins with enp, such as enp0s25 on my machine, is, as the name hints, an **E**ther**N**et **P**ci device; hence, enp. The numbers and letters following relate to the PCI bus to which the device is attached.

An interface name that begins with enx is an **E**ther**N**et e**X**ternal, typically USB, device. The numbers following are the MAC address of the device. Here is an example that I gleaned from AU: enx503eaa292ae3. Therefore, the MAC address is 50:3E:AA:29:2A:E3.

The same convention also applies to wireless; wlp is PCI and wlx is external, typically USB.

Comment: Thanks! This response answers my question for the most part. I needed to know how to format this when typing a command to randomize my MAC address.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

This command

```
$ ip link show
```

will show all your network devices, with their names and MAC addresses (if they have one).